# Are there any cons or missing features in Nitro PDF Professional versus Adobe Acrobat?

Tags: pdf, print-to-pdf, pdfcreator, adobe-acrobat

I've been looking into alternative PDF creation software such as [NitroPDF](http://www.nitropdf.com/index.asp).  It seems like a bargain at $99 a license compared to $300 for Acrobat.

The [feature comparison page](http://www.nitropdf.com/professional/compared.htm) gives a list of things that Nitro *does* do, but I'd like to know  if there are any features it is missing that Acrobat has.

EDIT: To be clear, I'm **not** looking for a list of alternatives, I'm specifically interested in knowing if there are any features from Acrobat that are not present in Nitro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Nitro PDF Professional 6 Review](http://www.zdnet.co.uk/reviews/content-creation/2009/07/16/nitro-pdf-professional-6-39684320/)

> Adobe's Acrobat is a polished product
>   with several features not offered by
>   Nitro PDF Professional (including the
>   ability to create and display
>   collections of related PDF content in
>   **Portfolios**, **redaction tools** to conceal
>   sensitive material within PDFs, and
>   **multimedia and 3D support**).

Answer (score 1):

I know my favorite thing about Acrobat 9 is that you can drag and drop pages from one document into the other. I don't believe that this is possible in Nitro.

I believe that both products offer a 30day trail.  Give them a spin and see what works for you.

Answer (score 1):

#### In Acrobat 10:

1. Enter key = Page Down; Shift+Enter = Page Up
2. You can't assign own shortcuts
3. You can use single-key shortcuts
4. Every word's search begins from the current page
5. Separated windows view only
6. Case sensitivity in Cyrillic's letter search is customizable

#### In Nitro 7:

1. Enter, Shift+Enter = Page Down
2. You can assign own shortcuts, but customizing sc and also buttons is uncomfortable (the list of functions is incomplete and full of duplicates)
3. You can't use single-key shortcuts – if you'll try, you won't be able to type that letter in a Search bar!
4. Every word's search begins from the first page
5. Tabbed view only
6. Case sensitivity in Cyrillic's letter search is always enabled!

Answer (score 0):

$99 is not a bargain when you consider the other alternatives.

I'd learn to use latex http://www.latex-project.org/ and get the texlive distribution http://www.tug.org/texlive/

Additionally, plenty of software has the ability to export to PDF (google docs, open office), and there are tools to merge pdfs together http://www.mergepdf.net/ (as well as command line utilities such as joinPDF)

Comment: I wasn't asking for other alternatives, I wanted to know if there were limitations of Nitro compared to Acrobat.

Answer (score 0):

For creation, free printer drivers for Windows abound:

[www.freepdfcreator.org](http://www.freepdfcreator.org) from Solid Documents

[www.primopdf.com](http://www.primopdf.com/index.aspx) from Nitro

[www.cutepdf.com](http://www.cutepdf.com/Products/CutePDF/writer.asp)

Comment: again, I'm aware of the plethora of alternatives, I'm looking for specific information on Nitro itself since it has all the merging, conversion to word, annotation and scanning features of Acrobat, but also has OCR and image editing.  What I'm wondering is if there are features I'd miss from Acrobat if it got it.

Answer (score 0):

Computerworld just published this review of PDF editors

http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9192927/Acrobat_and_its_alternatives_4_ways_to_edit_PDFs_